# How to add an ".mk" include line in the generated makefile with a CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: makefile, include, cmake

I'm trying to "convert" a makefile to cmake.
It has this line

```
include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk
```

I want my `CMakeLists.txt` to **add this line at the top of the generated makefile**.

I already have a makefile that works, but I'm not able to make it work with CMake, and I need it to be able to use this `CMakeLists.txt` for other platforms.

Comment: I think this is not the intended way to use CMake. The whole goal behind CMake is to be independent of platforms and build systems (like Makefiles or Visual Studio solutions). Hence, including special content in the generated Makefile is against the design decisions in CMake since the generated Makefile is simply one of many possibilities to build the project and is treated as a necessary artifact instead of something the user should edit.

Answer (score 0):

> add_subdirectory

I will say, try to use [add_subdirectory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html). You will have to write a differentsecond `CMakeLists.txt` for the common.mk, like you have written against first makefile. Then you can have add_subdirectory line as the first line in the first CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory($(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools)
```

In the tools folder write the other CMakeLists.txt which will create *common.mk*. While running cmake the first line (add_subdirectory) will get executed, which will execute CMakeLists.txt of the `common` folder.

IMO, this seems like an appropriate way of doing what you are asking, may not be one of the fastest method.

Comment: I don't want to create the common.mk, it's already in NaCL sdk folder, under tools.  But what I want is to have this line include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk at the top of my generated Makefile.  I don't know if I'm clear about what I'm trying to do